# Load wordpress content in other domain

Tags: php, loop, wp-load.php

I've made some researches on google but can't get the right answer.

I need to get my wordpress loops outside a domain using php file.

For example: I have a website hosted with **www.mysite.com** using wordpress. And an other one is **www.secondwebsite.com** using only php.

I would love to use something like the wp-load.php to use my loops in my php files.

Thanks a lot,

jhon

---

I can't get the server path rightly... Any ideas?

Here are my different path:

PHP FILE THAT NEED TO LOAD wp-load.php:

`/home/faver/domains/facebook.faver.be/www/lili`

Folder where the wp-load.php is:

`/home/lbpl/www/`

I tried this:

```
<?php
//Include WordPress
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../../../../../lbpl/www/wp-load.php');


query_posts('showposts=1');
?>

<?php while (have_posts()):
      the_post(); ?>
      <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
      <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more...</a></p>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

But not working. I think I can't go to the `/home` directory cuz of the FTP rights.

Thanks for the help

Jhon

Comment: Nothing new. Can't get my answer anywhere. Anyone know how I can get custom_post_type outside wordpress, and other domain? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This isn't a forum, if you have new information, post it as a comment on a question or an answer, don't respond in a new answer unless the response IS the answer to your question. You can also edit your own question to add new information.

Answer (score 1):

You mean:
`<?php
include "http://www.sample.com/wp-load.php";`

This setting is disabled/not allowed by default in most web servers (php.ini) so you can not use the include to include the files from a remote address for security reasons.

If you still want to allow inclusion of remote files, the directive `allow_url_include must be set to`On`(or 1) in`php.ini`.

But again it is a bad practice, in a security-oriented point of view. Often it is generally disabled.

Alternative is to use the feed. Parse the feed of the WordPress installation and use the content from this part. A another alternative is the XMLRPC surface, but the feed is easy to use and have all content parts.

Comment: Tried, but not working ! And i think allow_url_include is bad for injections !

Comment: Right, very insecure. That was my point to hint to parse the feed, secure and fast, cashable.

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to use wordpress json api. As bueltge mentioned the rss feed is one way to get your content but json api couldbe better in this case :)

Option one is to use http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/ option two would be the jetpack json api.